# chat.arqade.com gives a 404

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, arqade-migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [blog.arqade.com doesn't redirect to our blog](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4869/blog-arqade-com-doesnt-redirect-to-our-blog)

### Not Found

---

HTTP Error 404. The requested question is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find that this new domain will redirect to chat.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Hmm, could we possibly have it redirect to http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=gaming.stackexchange.com instead?