# blog.arqade.com doesn't redirect to our blog

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, arqade-migration

### The question you are looking for has not been started yet.

We are happy to provide resources for developers that want to supplement their site with a blog and show active interest from community members that are willing to report bugs such as this.

For more information on what blog.arqade.com should point to, please [read our blog entry](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/).

[There is a dedicated chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-briqade) to help you get started and fix our community blog. Feel free to drop in and say hi!

Comment: A new fix has been added - this should've fixed this again.

Comment: @GraceNote [This has been broken](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/8692/23) and [it broke our close reasons](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/8698/23), too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The redirect has been set up and is now working. (:

Comment: Your backward smiley face confuses me